# SSRS Reports data displaying from second page of the report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Recently we have migrated all RDLs from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008, all reports are working fine except one report.

Only header and footer of the report are showing in the first page of the report, actual data even it is just 1 line showing in second page of the report.

Any idea?

Comment: Check to see if there is a page break at start.

Comment: no, there is no page break. Same report works fine on SSRS 2005.